# variance of b1 and b2 calculation question

Tags: self-learning, variance, least-squares

I am revising how to prove the variance of b1 is greater than that of b2. However I am having trouble with the maths. Could someone please tell me how I get from step 1 to step 2? Could you please explain all steps? My maths isn't very strong.[image]

I just dont understand how we got from A to B with both b values.

[image]

Comment: Hint: if $x \leq y$, then $1/x \geq 1/y$

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand why the convexity argument holds for a vector $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$, as this is presently stated without any proof.

Let $\bar x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ be the arithmetic mean of the $x_i$s.  Then
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x + \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left((x_i - \bar x)^2 + 2\bar x (x_i - \bar x) + \bar x^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 + 2 \bar x \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) + \sum_{i=1}^n \bar x^2 \\
&= \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2\biggr) + 0 + n \bar x^2
\\ &\ge n \bar x^2,
\end{align*}$$
where the middle term $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) = -n \bar x + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = -n \bar x + \bar x = 0,$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 \ge 0$$ with equality occurring if $x_i = \bar x$ for all $i$, because the sum of the squares of real numbers is never negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \sum x^{2} &\ge \frac{\left( \sum x \right)^{2}}{n} \\[5pt]
%
  \frac{\sum x^{2}}{n} &\ge \frac{\left( \sum x \right)^{2}}{n^{2}} \\[5pt]
%
  \overline{x^{2}} &\ge \bar{x}^{2}
%
\end{align}
$$

The average of the squares is greater than or equal to the square of the average.